# Getting Information on Tolls Encountered using Map APIs

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap, here-api

I am working on a project that helps avoiding in standing long queue to pay tolls, so i was looking for a API that gives me the toll data ( tolls encountered ) for the route entered.

I tried looking for APIs that do the same, but as of now i could only come across this website that lists me the tolls encountered for a specified route

http://nhtis.org/map.htm

Is there any API that does the same ?

Comment: While OSM has [toll information](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:toll) I don't know of any service that can provide this information along a specific route. However you can download this toll data and do the route matching yourself.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly i can download the toll data?

Comment: One possible way is to use [Overpass API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) and download all *ways* with a *toll* key inside the bounding box you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE provides an API that allows you to get info about toll costs for a specific route. 
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/toll-cost/topics/introduction.html
(Disclosure: I'm working at HERE, but not on mentioned product)